# Rails how to make a route that catches all paths EXCEPT one

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Hi I need to make a rails route that catches all paths except a certain one. I tried the following to catch all paths in my app, and that worked great, but now I need to save one path for something else

```
match '*path', to: 'main#index'
```

Other path

```
match '/auth/twitter/callback' => 'sessions#create'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the routes, the order matters.
Try to put your wildcard constraint on the bottom of routes file.